# Excel Recalc all EXCEPT for query updates

Tags: excel, pivot-table

I have a very large database that comes from a sequel server - I update it once a day.

It feeds several pivot tables, some of which use date range (calculated fields) within the database to display segments of the data.

When I change the cells that feed the formulas in the database, I need to recalculate those formulas and the pivot tables. I do not want to REFRESH the feed from the sequel server which takes up two minutes to populate at times.

I need a quick VBA code to UPDATE ALL except for the data feed....

Any ideas?

Mark

(also - when I use the Recalc macro it recalcs the pivot tables first and then updates the queries in the background...seems backwards, although it doesn't matter as I have updated the queries already)

Comment: Sub Recalc_all()
'
' Recalc_all Macro
' Update everything in workbook
'

'
    ActiveWorkbook.RefreshAll
End Sub

Comment: That didn't format like it showed in my copy/paste.... it appears linebreaks are ignored...sorry